# Is the "add to cart" button useful in product listings?

Tags: e-commerce

I see a lot of e-commerce templates in which the items in the product listing page have an "add to cart" button.

In my experience when online shopping I never clicked that button, because before I buy I need more information (like what you see in the single-product page).

So, since I'm building an e-commerce website for a client and she wants a grid of products in her homepage, I'm thinking about replacing that button with a "product detail": one that just points to the single-product page. Is it a good idea or does the average user expect an "add to cart" button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the business. Sometimes a customer already knows what they're looking for, or has previously shopped and made the decision, and being able to "grab and check out" is convenient.

I don't think forcing another click (and then a return-to-list click) will cost you many consumer sales. Pros want as much streamlining as they can get.

Answer (score 5):

I think its bit tricky question. Its totally depends on the your target market. If your target market is mature enough you can have add to cart button straight forward. but if not they have to dig into details.

Using model box option may make this much easier. But i recommend to have both options.

Answer (score 1):

As well as being dependent on your target market, you should also consider the type of products being displayed on the page. Would your customers want/need more information? eg a pack of 10 black clothes hangers with an image of the product does not warrant a click through to a detailed description and delivery options page, and then another click for the order button. However, a full size fridge/freezer on the grid with a single image of the product really must have the option to click for full details and more images.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are doing grocery shopping, YES**

Its good to have Add to cart and Quick View both the buttons on product listing.

Moreover I think it depends a lot on targeted market and behaviour of shopping. i.e As I mentioned If you are selling **online groceries**, It makes lot of sense to put the "Add to cart" button on listing page because probability of buying multiple items is very very high. Its like the way you buy offline groceries. You pick an item and put it in cart.

On the other side...

While shopping electronics or mobile phones , it makes sense to put Quick View button where user can just get a glance of product information and add to cart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the *best possible click-to-sale conversion rate*. Why remove the chance for a customer to add something to their cart at the earliest possible point? Or in other words, why require the customer to drill down into the details to add the item to their cart? If I know what I want, I have no reason to dive into the details.

[NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com) does it the right way.  They allow you to add it to your cart from the get go. Take a look below:

[image]

They have the image of the product with its detail link linking to the product details.  Beside the product image, they have reviews that link to the product details as well, but with the reviews scrolled into view.  Then they have a few product details below the product image along with the price, discount, and shipping. Beneath that is an ADD TO CART button that allows you to grab it right off the search page.  And just for completeness' sake, here's the product details page:

[image]